# What tense is this? "to be + to verb"

Tags: tenses, be

For example, "If we are to achieve our objectives..." or "What is to be done?"

What tense is this? In my understanding, we're talking about the future, but it's a weird *sort of* "tense" I haven't studied before.

Comment: I'm not sure your two examples are "the same" usage. You could make the first the same as the second by recasting to *If our objectives are to be achieved* (passive, loses the "subject" ***we***), or make the second equivalent to the first with *What are we to do?* (active verb form, with subject/verb reversal because it's a question).

Comment: "Are" and "is" are present tense verb-forms so the sentences are present tense.  "To achieve our objectives" and "to be done" are both non-finite clauses i.e.  tenseless. The are functioning as catenative complements of "be" and have no bearing on the tense.

Comment: @BillJ: Or (had past circumstances been otherwise) - *What would have been to be done?* Which I'm sure *you* could "deconstruct", but my eyes just start to glaze over.

Answer (score -1):

'To be to' is one of the modal verbs. It has the meaning of obligation.
The verb 'to be' is in the Present Simple, though its modal meaning has future reference.